# django subprocess p.wait() doesn't return web

Tags: django, subprocess

With a django button, I need to launch multiples music (with random selection).

In my models.py, I have two functions 'playmusic' and 'playmusicrandom' :

```
def playmusic(self, music):
    if self.isStarted():
        self.stop()

    command = ("sudo /usr/bin/mplayer "+music.path)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command+str(music.path), shell=True)
    p.wait()


def playmusicrandom(request):    
    conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'])
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM webgui_music")
    list_id = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]

    ### Get three IDs randomly from the list ###
    selected_ids = random.sample(list_id, 3)

    for i in (selected_ids):
        music = Music.objects.get(id=i)
        player.playmusic(music)
```

With this code, three musics are played (one after the other), but the web page is just "Loading..." during execution...
Is there a way to display the refreshed web page to the user, during the loop ?? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is blocked from returning anything to the web server while it is waiting for `playmusicrandom()` to finish.

You need to arrange for `playmusicrandom()` to do its task *after* you're returned the HTTP status from the view.

This means that you likely need a thread (or similar solution).

Your view will have something like this:

```
import threading

t = threading.Thread(target=player_model.playmusicrandom,
                             args=request)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
return HttpResponse()
```

This code snippet came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068945/django-long-running-asynchronous-tasks-with-threads-processing), where you will find more detailed information about the issues you face and possible solutions.

Comment: Great ! Thank you , it works. Just, my hardware has one processor listed in `cat /proc/cpuinfo` (raspberry pi).  Which of methods is more advised ? (Thread, Multiprocess, etc...).

Comment: Sorry to post an issue about this solution, it works, but my stop function stop only the current mplayer process (pkill), and I would to kill the entire thread, but I've seen that was not really possible... ?   Do you have an idea ?